# Unable to create Professional Edition scratch org with AuthorApex

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, professional-edition

I'm attempting to create a Professional Edition with the `AuthorApex` feature (full config file below).

This fails with the following error

> ERROR running force:org:create:  The REST API is not enabled for this
>   Organization.

The scratch org **is** created however in the DevHub -- I just cannot access it since no credentials are shown. And I can't generate a password, since

`sfdx force:user:password:generate  --targetusername [username]`

gives:

> ERROR running force:user:password:generate:  No org configuration
>   found for name [username]

Other observations:

- It works fine if I remove `AuthorApex` from the config
- It works fine with `"edition": "Enterprise"` (even with `AuthorApex`)
- A colleague is able to generate an org with the desired config and the same DevHub
- I am using `sfdx-cli/7.1.4-79f97a7df8 darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3`

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Jelle

=============== scratch org config ===============

```
{
    "orgName": "Test Professional With Apex",
    "edition": "Professional",
    "hasSampleData": "true",
    "features": ["AuthorApex"],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "s1EncryptedStoragePref2": false,
            "chatterEnabled": true
        }
    },
    "adminEmail" : "email@test.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Professional Edition doesn't get Apex, so you can't enable it. This is probably an oversight, since there'd be no way to develop against an Professional Edition for managed package purposes, which is presumably why you'd want to do this. You should reach out to the DX team either on the Trailblazer Community or Twitter. For now, your workaround would be to use Enterprise Edition as the org type.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @sfdcfox

You are right that the goal is to develop our managed package.

What's weird though is that my colleague _is_ able to create a PE scratch org with AuthorApex enabled -- so it is possible, it just doesn't work for me.... Or more precisely: my org does get created but I can't log into it as the creation or retrieval of credentials fails

Comment: @JellevanGeuns That's odd, I wouldn't have expected it to work at all ever. Have you tried asking on the Trailblazer Community?